# codeblocks in 16.04 can't copy/cut and paste more than once

Tags: 16.04, code-blocks

I've installed codeblocks in ubuntu 16.04.  I first installed version 13.12+dfsg-4 from the universe repository. Then I installed version 16.01~ubuntu16.04.1 from ppa:damien-moore/codeblocks-stable ppa.

Both versions have the problem that cut or copy and a subsequent paste only works at most once per session.  Attempting to paste either from the edit menu or with control-v does nothing.  It still works to paste text that has been copied from a different application.  It seems codeblocks loses the ability to copy things into the clipboard.

This makes what would otherwise be a great application unusable.  Any help or suggestions for fixing this are welcome.

Comment: I'm running Codeblocks 16.01 on Ubuntu 16.04 but I am not noticing any copy or paste problems. Has it been working for you on other versions of Ubuntu or earlier Codeblocks versions?

Comment: It works on one of my machines and doesn't work on another one.